# Is it possible to write a method for an XAttribute AND XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, types, type-conversion

`XAttribute` and `XElement` both derive from the `XObject` type.

Both have a `Value` property.

So far, this is what I've come up with to do what I want :

```
string FooMyXObject( XObject bar ){
    if ( bar.NodeType == NodeType.Element )
        return ( bar as XElement ).Value;
    else if ( bar.NodeType == NodeType.XAttribute )
        return ( bar as XAttribute ).Value;
    else
        throw new Exception( "Generic Fail Message" );
}
```

This feels clunky. I'm hoping there is some way to make this less clunky. Some way of accessing the `Value` property from the `XObject`, since they both have a string property names `Value`.

Is this possible, or am I just forced to doing it in thus clunky fashion?

Comment: [`XText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`XComment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcomment(v=vs.110).aspx) also have a `Value` property with no common base class.  It's a bit annoying really.  This is exactly the situation where an interface `IHasValue` would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast `bar` to `dynamic` to avoid separate branches:

```
string FooMyXObject( XObject bar ){
    if (bar.NodeType == NodeType.Element || bar.NodeType == NodeType.XAttribute)
        return ((dynamic)bar).Value;
    else
        throw new Exception( "Generic Fail Message" );
}
```

Comment: I like this. It certainly is better than what I was doing ( and the `GetType( ).GetProperty( "Value" ).GetValue( Bar ).ToString( )` approach ).

Comment: There is a performance hit when using `dynamic` like this. The code provided by OP in his question will behave better in terms of performance and I'd suggested using it instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the .Value property is defined on the XObject, Then you can write this pretty simply using generics.

i.e.

```
string FooMyXObject<T>(T bar) where T : XObject
{
    return bar.Value;
}
```

If that is not the case then you should consider moving it to the base class if it is common functionality of the derived classes.

Edit:
Your code is pretty much right if it is the case the Value property is not on the base class.  Maybe you could refactor it like so using a case for easier extension:

```
string FooMyXObject(XObject bar)
{
   switch(bar.NodeType)
   {
      case NodeType.Element:
          return ( bar as XElement ).Value;
      case NodeType.XAttribute:
          return ( bar as XAttribute ).Value;
      default:
          throw new Exception( "Generic Fail Message" );
   }
}
```

or just for fun

```
string FooMyXObject(XObject bar)
    {
       try
       {
           dynamic temp = bar;
           return temp.Value;
       } 
       catch ()
       {
           throw new Exception( "Generic Fail Message" );
       }
    }
```

Comment: `Value` is not a property defined on the `XObject` type.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given by @meganaut and @dasblinkenlight are both correct, but there is more to be said.

In the `System.Linq.Xml` namespace, `XElement` and `XAttribute` both extend `XObject`, but they each define their `Value` property separately, so this kind of branching or the use of the `dynamic` type is required.

In other object models, generics might be usable in a similar scenario as suggested by @meganaut.